# How to enable open with explorer for document library in sharepoint server

Tags: 2013

i have a publishing site and a document library and i want to enable open with explorer to copy files, we have one wfe server and one app server

Answer (score 1):

It's available out of the box, provided that you use a 32-bit version of Internet Explorer.